# Is there any way I can view the full source code of a webpage that uses Angular UI-Router?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

For example, if you were to go to http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/, no matter what page on that webpage.. if you Right Click --> View Source, the source code is always the same.

Is there any way I can view the HTML the browser is seeing in full all together?  As in.. the "ui-view" portion of the Angular code cuts to another portion of HTML on a different page.. and I would like to see how the browser views all the HTMl when put together as one full page.

Comment: open the developer console of your browser and look at the sources and elements

Comment: @Jorg hey jorg thanks for responding.  let me try that out.. right now it seems like by doing that.. i have to still dig through the code to see which page is loading and then embed it into the main view to get an idea of how it looks like fully together.  was hoping for an easier way

Comment: @Jorg ah ya you're right.. the Elements was what I was looking for.  ty!

Comment: View Source is only what gets sent from server

Comment: @charlietfl ah okay i didn't know that.  thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome: press F12 to open the Developer Tools, then go to the 'Sources' tab:

[image]

All currently loaded sources are displayed on the left, and clicking them shows the code in the middle.

Comment: The Elements tab was actually what I was looking for, but this helped.  Ty